# which is better, string or char[], when I want to read/write from a file.dat(binary file)? c++

Tags: c++, file

**C++:**

1-which is better,`string` or `char[]`, when I want to read/write from a **binary file**?

2-what is the best way to read/write a **binary file** in general?

3-When I see **c++ projects**, I frequently notice that they use **char[] instead of string** to write. Why is that?

4- How to read/write form a binary file using **string**?

***Example***: University Management System C++ Project*

In this project, the creator used **char[]** to read and write the name of student, college, location, last name, ... etc.

**Note**: the creator uses **file.read\write((char *)this, sizeof(name of class))***

Comment: It depends, what is the actual contents of the file? Wouldn't it be better to *deserialize* the contents into actual structures that corresponds to the data in the file?

Comment: What I usually do is open the file, determine its size. Allocate a std::vector<char> with that size (use appropiate constructor) and read file into the vector's data.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude " Wouldn't it be better to deserialize the contents into actual structures that corresponds to the data in the file?" can you explain what you mean thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem with using `std::string` is that any 0 byte will be interpreted as end of string. I wouldn't recommend using `std::string` unless you're sure you've got a file or a part of a file not containing a 0 byte in an unexpected place. For reaing structs you cannot really guarantee this in general, since there may be padding between member variables that could be filled with arbitrary data... Furthermore note that structs may not always be readable the way presented in the last line. vtables could be problematic as could be reading the same data in a 32 and 64 bit program, ect...

Comment: @PKramer why do you use this way?

Comment: Unlike text-files, binary files usually have some kind of structure. For example an file containing a picture usually have some data describing the picture, like its size and so on, followed by the actual picture data. If you want to work with the data in the file in a meaningful way, you need to know its internal structure, not just as an array of bytes. By reading the data into actual structures (classes and objects) in the code helps with that.

Comment: @fabian Thanks for this warning, I've curiosity  about your way that you're using

Comment: @fabian Actually that's not entirely true... A `std::string` object can contain embedded zeros, if you explicitly set the length when initializing it. Of course, if converting it to a C-style string (with e.g. `data()` or `c_str()`) those embedded zeros will act as terminator.

Comment: I use it that way to read the whole file into memory in one read without either allocating too much or too little memory. But after that you still have to get data from the buffer into data structures of your own. So like @Someprogrammerdude said understanding serialization is a good point to start. https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization#serialize-binary-format

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Can you recommend to me a way to using?

Comment: @LoayTarek -- `file.read\write((char )this, sizeof(name of class))` -- Let's see an example of the class you are attempting to write to a binary file.  This will not work if the class is not trivially-copyable.  Stack overflow is littered with disappointed posters that realize their "binary reading/writing" code won't work with what they are using.

Comment: What is the *purpose* of your program? What is it supposed to actually do with the data in the file? Before you tell us that, and what kind of file you're actually attempt to read, we can't help you in any meaningful way.

Comment: @PKramer ok i get it thank you so mush i appreciate your effort .

Comment: With that said, if you just need access to the raw bytes, disregarding any structure of the file, then why not *memory map* the file instead?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you're right this is explanation of the project (https://www.codewithc.com/university-management-system-project-c/) and i'm sorry for these questions

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That is a good warning! And even trivially copyable could go wrong when moving a save file from one system/platform to another. You really need to marshal data into very well defined data chunks. E.g. an int is always a 4 bytes little endian ordered sequence of bytes in the file.

Comment: Can anyone point me the recourse to learn more about the binary files, how to deal with and understanding?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the entire file into an array, then I recommend `std::vector<unsigned char>`.

If you want to read the file in chunks, then `unsigned char[]` is typically fine.